# Проблема с корректным double

Tags: java, android, double

Возможно, кто-то найдет мой вопрос дурацким. Возможно, кто-то опять скажет, тип, иди учи. Но сейчас мне реально не понятно, в чем ошибка...И я общался с людьми, которые достаточно хорошо знают jav'у, но и они ничего толкового не сказали.
А теперь, вопрос. Сейчас покажу куски кода, и объясню ниже. 
Вот код.

**ScreenOne1.class**

```
package ru.N.w;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.yandex.metrica.YandexMetrica;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScreenOne1 extends Activity {
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private LocationListener mLocationListener;
double txt1;
        double txt2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.screen_one1);

                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();


                // Операции для выбранного пункта меню
                switch (id) {
                        case R.id.action_cat1:
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenOne1.class);
                                startActivity(intent1);
                                return true;
                        case R.id.action_cat2:
                                Intent intent2 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenTwo.class);
                                startActivity(intent2);
                                return true;
                        case R.id.action_cat3:
                                Intent intent3 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenThree.class);
                                startActivity(intent3);
                                return true;
                        case R.id.action_cat4:
                                Intent intent4 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenFour.class);
                                startActivity(intent4);
                                return true;
                        default:
                                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
        }

        public void on_to(View view) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenOne1.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
        }

        public void on_from(View view) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenOne2.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
        }

        public void on_all(View view) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(ScreenOne1.this, ScreenOne3.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                YandexMetrica.onResumeActivity(this);
                // включаем отслеживание
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);

                // при использовании сетей типа GSM
                 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
                //        mLocationListener);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
                YandexMetrica.onPauseActivity(this);



                super.onPause();
        }
        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

                        txt1 = 55.900815 ;

                        txt2 = 37.742203;
                }


                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps выключен",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps включен",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

        }

        GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(txt1, txt2, "hhh", "h", 1);

        GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[]{


                new GeoPoint(55.900815, 37.742203, "Т", "https://", 1),
                new GeoPoint(55.890191, 37.726024, "П", "https://", 1)};
                GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
                Arrays.asList(locations));


        public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.station_name);
                helloTextView.setText(nearest.getName());
        }


     }
```

А теперь в чем ошибка. 
Когда я прописываю координаты вот так, то выдается неправильная точка(подозреваю, что вместо правильных txt1 и txt2 приходят 0 и 0).
а когда прописываю прямо здесь, тоесть `GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint( 55.900815, 37.742203, "hhh", "h", 1);` , то точка выдается правильная. Значит, дело с этими txt1 и txt2.
Так в чем проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике что именно у вас там.

Comment: А где вы устанавливаете значения `txt1` и `txt2`? Я вижу только захардкоженные значения. Если не хардкодить, то значения у них будут по умолчанию нули. Так как `GeoPoint` вы создаёте при инициализации класса (то есть, до того, как будет выполнен метод `onLocationChange`), в конструктор `GeoPoint` передаются нули. P.S. Читайте [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) и следуйте им. Ваш код очень сложно читать.

Answer (score 1):

Этот код вызывается ДО того как будут изменены значения txt1 и txt2 с 0 на другие значения:

```
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(txt1, txt2, "hhh", "h", 1);
```

Я так понимаю что ты рассчитывал что txt1 и txt2 это ссылки на объекты и при изменении их позже они будут меняться внутри объекта GeoPoint?
Ответ неверен. double это примитивный тип, не ссылка на объект и в GeoPoint будут только те значения, которые ты указываешь при его создании, т.е. те которыми инициализированы txt1 и txt2 изначально.

Что можно сделать - это пересоздавать GeoPoint с новыми значениями или лучше, если это возможно, указывать новые значения существующему объекту. (setXXX)

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    txt1 = 55.900815;

    txt2 = 37.742203;

    currentLocation = new GeoPoint(txt1, txt2, "hhh", "h", 1);
 }
```